# Determining if a set of hexagons on a grid can tile the plane

Tags: geometry, computational-geometry, discrete-geometry, tiling

Suppose I have a regular grid of identical hexagons that tile the plane, that is a hexagonal lattice.

How can I determine if a connected subset of these hexagons (i.e. a poly-hex) can tile the plane by translations that form a (Bravais) lattice? For reference, here is a picture:

[image]

The four shapes on the right can tile the plane, while the left-most shape cannot.

Comment: You mean just translations, no rotations allowed? That may be decidable.

Comment: That is correct, only translations, and no rotations. Not only that, but the overall tiling should be periodic.

Comment: The polyhexes that tile by translation, up to order 9, can be found by links from http://www.polyomino.org.uk/mathematics/polyform-tiling/ --- e.g., there are 6572 polyhexes of order 9, of which only 387 tile by translation. There are also references there to the literature. See also http://mysite.verizon.net/vze16nctz/Tilings/Article/planar.ps

Comment: @GerryMyerson Link in your comment seems to be dead, by I would make an educated guess that it is the paper Glennn C. Rhoads: "Planar Tilings by Polyominoes, Polyhexes, and Polyiamonds" http://gcrhoads.byethost4.com/Tilings/index.html?i=1 http://gcrhoads.byethost4.com/Tilings/Article/planar.ps https://doi.org/10.1016/j.cam.2004.05.002

Answer (score 0):

John Conway obtained an algorithm for deciding (a particular case of) the tiling problem with polyminoes and polyhexes.

Such algorithm is explained by Thurston [here](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/37963/lecture-notes-by-thurston-on-tiling).